# Java equivalent of perl unpack function

Tags: java, perl

I have a perl code (say client) which sends packed data as HTTP POST to another perl code running on apache mod_perl module (say server).

In client side, I have the pack function like this,

```
$postData = pack("N a*", length($metaData), $metaData);
```

From perl pack document, it seems,

```
N -> An unsigned long (32-bit) in "network" (big-endian) order.
a -> A string with arbitrary binary data, will be null padded.
```

Now the $postData will be sent to server using perl LWP User Agent.

In the server side perl, we used to unpack like this,

```
# first reading the metaData Length
my $buf;
$request->read($buf, 4); #$request is apache request handler
my $metaDataLength = unpack("N", $buf);

# now read the metaData itself
$request->read($buf, $metaDataLength);
```

Now I have to do this server side data parsing in java (moving away from perl for some reasons). I have searched google for this and it seems to be not a single line solution as in perl. Some suggested to write our own unpack function. I am using java 1.7 version.

Is there any simple solution available in java for the above server side data parsing ?

**Edit**: Thanks Elliot for 'ByteBuffer' idea. The following code works fine for me,

```
InputStream is = request.getInputStream(); //request is HTTPServletRequest
byte[] bArr = new byte[4]; //reading first 4 bytes to get metaDataLength
int bytesRead = is.read(bArr);
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bArr);
int metaDataLength = buf.getInt(); //shows value matches with clientside perl code.
```

Comment: You might start with [jerl](https://code.google.com/p/jerl/).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, As we planned to move away from perl, I don't think 'jerl' is the right way to go. Can you please suggest something for this 'unpack' alone in java ?

Comment: Not directly, nor easy. You can (presumably) use a [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) to do it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, Thanks for your idea. I have updated my question with a solution based on ByteBuffer. Please take a look if it is fine.

Comment: looks reasonable to me.

Comment: Although this will only work if $metaData is less than 2147483647 (which may be entirely reasonable for your code)

Comment: Please don't write the answer in your question; create a real answer and accept it (after a while).

Answer (score 0):

potentially [JBBP](https://code.google.com/p/java-binary-block-parser/) can be such one

```
final int value = JBBPParser.prepare("int;").parse(theInputStream).findFieldForType(JBBPFieldInt.class).getAsInt();
```